# Loop through filenames in folder and subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #sh j

find . -name "*first*" && echo "file found" || echo "file not found"

read -p "Run command $foo? [yn]" answer

case "$answer" in
y*) find . -type f -exec rename 's/(.*)\/(.*)first(.*)/$1\/beginning_$2changed$3/' {} + ;;

n*) echo "not renamed" ;;
esac
fi
```

I want the script to loop through folder and subfolders and find files that contain certain string and then have an option to rename the file or let it be(That is the y/n option) after selection the script should continue finding.

Also i have a problem that says "syntax error unexpected token 'fi' "

Comment: actually, why did you put a `fi` at the end? there does not seem to be any `if` in your code.

Comment: If you want to have the variables expanded, you need double quotes in the rename expression. Also, paste your snippet in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to track the errors

Comment: Oh thanks, It's working now. But i still have problem that the code renames all the files after the first case.

Comment: If you want to prompt for *each* rename then you need to loop over the filenames or better use `-ok ;` instead of `-exec +` (you need the `;` version because you need `find` to prompt for each file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   #bin/bash

   handle_file(){

            local file=$0
            local pattern=some_pattern
            if [[ $(grep -c ${pattern} ${file}) -gt 0 ]];
            then
                    ......................................
                    do anything you want with your ${file}
                    ......................................
            fi
    }
    export -f handle_file

    find . -type f -exec bash -c 'handle_file "$@"' {} \;
```

`handle_file` is a function that will be invoked as `handle_function <filename>`, so the `<filename>` is available as `$0` inside the function.